# Protractor - can't read property bind of undefined for EC.textToBePresentInElement

Tags: javascript, exception, selenium-webdriver, protractor

My spec:

```
  it('displays user details page of an active user', function () {
        var userDetailsPage = new UserDetailsPage();
        var usersPage = new UsersPage();
        expectVisibilityOf(usersPage.thirdRow, 'element firstRow was not visible ');
        var positionUsersTableThirdRow = usersPage.thirdRowPosition.getText();
        var idUsersTableThirdRow = usersPage.thirdRowId.getText();
        var emailUsersTableThirdRow = usersPage.thirdRowEmail.getText();
        clickWithWait(usersPage.thirdRow);
        browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(userDetailsPage.position.value), WAIT_TIMEOUT, 'element position was not clickable ');
        browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(userDetailsPage.id), WAIT_TIMEOUT, 'element id was not clickable ');
        browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(userDetailsPage.email), WAIT_TIMEOUT, 'element email was not clickable ');

        browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(userDetailsPage.position, positionUsersTableThirdRow), 5000);
        browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(userDetailsPage.id, idUsersTableThirdRow), 5000);
        browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(userDetailsPage.email, emailUsersTableThirdRow), 5000);

        //expect(userDetailsPage.position.value.getText()).toEqual(positionUsersTableThirdRow);
        //expect(userDetailsPage.id.getText()).toEqual(idUsersTableThirdRow);
        //expect(userDetailsPage.email.getText()).toEqual(emailUsersTableThirdRow);
    });
```

Problem is that test works fine when I am using         `expect(element.getText()).toEqual();`  (these commented ones) but for protractor ExpectedCondition it fails with message about undefined bind - `Failed: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`.
What is the issue here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a simple copy-paste error. You need to use `userDetailsPage.position.value` instead of `userDetailsPage.position`:

```
positionUsersTableThirdRow.then(function (value) {
    browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(userDetailsPage.position.value, value), 5000);
});
```

Note that here I'm resolving `positionUsersTableThirdRow` explicitly with `then()`.

Comment: True, it solves binding exception but this time TimeoutError appears. Like it is waiting for something what is not present.

Comment: @Michal I'm not sure but should not you resolve the `positionUsersTableThirdRow` explicitly with `then()`?..

Comment: how ? could you correct my code  ? I am newbie in js.

Comment: @Michal btw, there was an update - can you check if it works for you? Thanks.